# What is the secure and standard way of testing form submissions with reCaptcha?

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, recaptcha

I have a lot of views with different forms, some forms have reCaptcha protection and some don't. Forms that have reCaptcha protection are critical (register, login, restore etc) and that's why they should be tested.

What I don't want to do:

1. Add any `debug`, `test` flags which turn reCaptcha off (insecure?).
2. Comment or uncomment reCaptcha HTML-block on each unit-test and deployment stage.

What is the standard way of testing forms with reCaptcha?

Comment: do you want to test it on production ? if not this should help : https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha-v2-what-should-i-do

Comment: Thx, I'll check it.

Comment: let me know if this helps, so i can add a proper answer

Comment: @YamenNassif, yep! It's what I really was looking for. Please, post as an answer and add two mentioned keys, so others could use them if came from search engines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will help you as the google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha-v2-what-should-i-do) says:

> I'd like to run automated tests with reCAPTCHA v2. What should I do?
>
> With the following test keys, you will always get No CAPTCHA and all
> verification requests will pass.
>
> - Site key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI
> - Secret key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe
>
> The reCAPTCHA widget will
> show a warning message to ensure it's not used for production traffic.

but don't forget to remove it on production lvls!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this, but you would define the site key as a parameter in your `parameters.yml` to be set.

If empty, then you can skip the validation, adding the field to the form, rendering on the view, etc.
Then you would just mock the `getParameter` for that key in your tests to return empty.

Comment: Yes, google goes for https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq . "For reCAPTCHA v3, create a separate key for testing environments.". Better is to do ourself, as you mention.

Comment: and yet for some reason, it got downvoted a few times